# How to set implicit routing in .net core 3

Tags: .net-core, routes

How do I define routes implicitly? For example I have a controller with name TodoController with some actions like Add, Get, Save.. And I don't want for each one specify the Route Attribute.

This is my code:

```
public class TodoController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult New()
    {
        return Ok();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Prova()
    {
        return Ok();
    }
```

and this is my startup.cs

```
         if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

My research results.

You can use 2 type of routing.

1.

```
services.AddMvc(option => option.EnableEndpointRouting = false).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0);



app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller}/{action}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
    );

});
```

`

2.

```
services.AddControllers();
  services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0);


app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

}
);
```

**BOTH variant worked with Rout attribute but don't have variant without him.**